# Hay alguna forma de recorrer un dictionary string mas eficientemente?

Tags: c#, .net

tengo un dictionary string `ultimasCompras` el cual me trae alrededor de  160.000 registros, el cual necesito comparar con otro dictionary string `productosBodegaData` que tiene alrededor de 90.000 registros, pero mi problema es que itero con un foreach cada registro para comparar con otro.
Hay alguna otra forma mas eficente de hacerlo.
Aquí dejo mi código :

```
@foreach (var row in ultimasCompras){
   int stockCentral   = 0 ;
   int stockRecepcion = 0 ;
   float stockTotales   = 0 ;

   foreach( var _row in productosBodegaData)
   {
       if (row["PRODUCTO"] == _row["Producto"])
       {
           stockTotales =  float.Parse( _row["cantidad"] ) ;
           break;
       }
       else
       {
           stockTotales = 0;
       }
   }
}
```

Cualquier sugerencia se agradece

Comment: Que criterios estas utilizando para traer dicha cantidad de registros? Seguro que no necesitas alguna condición?

Comment: Estás usando mal, las vistas son para mostrar información (y bueno, en algunos casos aplicar alguna lógica sencilla), todo eso es mejor colocarlo en el controlador, en un modelo, o si quieres algo más rápido, un viewBag. Por otro lado, te hace falta una suma de stocks, hay variables definidas sin usar... Si estás iniciando en ASP.net MVC te recomiendo este workshop que hice tiempo atrás: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY

Comment: Si esta información está en una base de datos hay una buena probabilidad que sea más rápido hacer este proceso dentro del motor, lo que te daría acceso a los índices de la DB.

Comment: porque veo un @foreach ? en que estas programando, eso no es solo c#

Comment: te animas a usar linq ?